# xcode scheme is different

Tags: ios, xcode

I downloaded an Xcode project from Assembla through source control in Xcode. After I downloaded and opened the project, it's opening in a different scheme called `ScanToMatch` (which is my previous project) instead of scheme called `FieldGuide`.

I tried to create a new scheme manually, but when I do this and run with the new scheme it crashes and behaves differently.

When I try the same process on a different machine, it works without any trouble. Is there any default scheme set in Xcode? If so, how can I reset it?

Comment: Schemes are project-based, so that doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mark the scheme as shared (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeManage.html) in the Xcode that you created it and commit that change. Update the code from Assembla in the other pc and try to see if the scheme is visible. Maybe that is the problem why you are not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Non-shared Xcode build schemes are stored in the `YourProject.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/user_name.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/` directory. Try following:

- Go to 'Manage Schemes' dialog, make sure the 'Autocreate schemes' checkmark is set
- Close Xcode
- Delete all files from that directory (don't forget to create back up copies prior to deletion files)
- Reopen Xcode.

If you wish to share build schemes between various machines then please use Shared Schemes (checkmark 'Shared' checkbox in the 'Manage Schemes' dialog for schemes you'd like to share). Shared schemes are stored in the `YourProject.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/` directory.

See also [Scheme Configuration Help](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeManage.html).